# Postback with CreateUserWizard

Tags: asp.net, createuserwizard

I have an RadUpload control in a CreateUserWizard. from a brief search on the internet,uploading requires postback while CreateUserWizard does not postback. Any idea how I can get the wizard to postback. or any other mechanism to upload a file during user registration.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the CreateUserWizard with Telerik, but as I pointed out in your other Telerik question: it's usually not a great idea to put Telerik control inside standard, or other third party controls. They generally don't react well to it.

If you need to use a Telerik component on top of another component, I usually "style" them on there. Something like:

```
<div style="left:200px;top:125px;"><telerik:RadComponent runat="server" something="whatever" /></div>
```

That said, I'm not sure CreateUserWizard is capable of postbacks. Can't you put a button somewhere, to generate a postback on click?

Comment: yes I can always use a button, but in my project all other uploads work without a upload button (gmail attachment style). So this might be a usability issue if i add a button

Comment: True. Consistency is imo one of the cornerstones of usability. How have you solved this on the other pages then? What upload component have you used?